Storing and accessing edge data in a graph characterized by its adjacency list representation in C++
I am currently solving a problem concerning graphs in Data Structures in C++. The exercise says I should "build on the adjacency list representation of a graph, so that a field named data of type KeyType is associated with each edge, where KeyType is a template parameter of a class template."
This paragraph explains my situation. I did a similar exercise for vertices, and it was easy to identify them as integers. However, now I have to identify edges of a graph as a variable and I was wondering what one and only variable I can use to identify each edge. Obviously, I need more than just a simple integer to characterize an edge, and I thought about pointers too, but I am having a hard time how "KeyType data" can refer to an edge of the graph. I am looking for comments or answers that can guide me in the right way in writing my program for this exercise.
Lastly, here are some assumptions about the input data. The edges as input are entered without repetition. For example, edge connecting vertices 1 and 2 are equivalent to edge connecting vertices 2 and 1. In addition the edges cannot be cyclical by nature. For example, node 3 cannot create a self-loop by proceeding to node 3.
I have attempted to associate each edge with an integer for the 'data' field and prepared two structs, each of them as struct Vertex and struct Edge but I don't know if this is the right way to proceed with structuring the graph.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

template<typename KeyType>
struct Vertex {
    KeyType data;
    Vertex() = default;
    explicit Vertex(const KeyType& identifier) : data(identifier) {}
};

template<typename KeyType>
struct Edge {
    KeyType data;
    int to;  // destination vertex index
    Edge() = default;
    Edge(const KeyType& edgeData, int toVertex) : data(edgeData), to(toVertex) {}
};

template<typename KeyType>
class Graph {
private:
    std::vector<Vertex<KeyType>> vertices;
    std::vector<std::vector<Edge<KeyType>>> adjacencyList;

public:
    void ReadAdjList() {
        int n;
        std::cout << "Enter the number of vertices: ";
        std::cin >> n;

        vertices.clear();
        adjacencyList.clear();
        vertices.resize(n);
        adjacencyList.resize(n);

        std::cout << "\nEnter data for each vertex:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cout << "Vertex " << i << " data: ";
            KeyType vertexData;
            std::cin >> vertexData;
            vertices[i] = Vertex<KeyType>(vertexData);
        }

        std::cout << "\nFor each vertex, enter its adjacent vertices and edge data.\n";
        std::cout << "Enter -1 to end the list for a vertex.\n\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cout << "Enter edges for vertex " << i << " (" << vertices[i].data << "):\n";
            while (true) {
                std::cout << "Adjacent vertex (-1 to end): ";
                int adjacent;
                std::cin >> adjacent;

                if (adjacent == -1) break;

                if (adjacent < 0 || adjacent >= n || adjacent == i) {
                    std::cout << "Invalid vertex. Please enter a number between 0 and " 
                              << (n - 1) << " (excluding " << i << ") or -1 to end.\n";
                    continue;
                }

                KeyType edgeData;
                std::cout << "Enter edge data for " << vertices[i].data 
                          << " -> " << vertices[adjacent].data << ": ";
                std::cin >> edgeData;

                adjacencyList[i].emplace_back(edgeData, adjacent);
            }
        }
    }

    void PrintAdjList() const {
        std::cout << "\nAdjacency List:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << vertices[i].data << " -> ";
            for (const auto& edge : adjacencyList[i]) {
                std::cout << "(" << vertices[edge.to].data << ", " << edge.data << ") ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Graph<int> graph;
    graph.ReadAdjList();
    graph.PrintAdjList();
    return 0;
}


I think you're already going wrong with the vertices, and I think that's because you're unclear about what the book is saying.

I did a similar exercise for vertices, and it was easy to identify them as integers.

What's "them"? Because vertices themselves are not integers. Vertex<KeyType> is a type template. Even Vertex<int> is not an integer. It holds an integer.
There's no particular reason why a Graph should hold the same data type in its edges as it uses in its vertices. For instance, in the graph coloring problem, color is solely a property of the vertices. In that problem, edges have no associated data (Their KeyType would be void, see your textbook about template specialization)
